# Clone Raid 0 hardware array to bigger external disks?

Tags: windows, ssd, external-hard-drive, raid

I have a laptop I bought used, has dual Samsung 500gb m.2 SSDs in and Intel RST RAID 0 array. I'm running out of space on it and can't add additional drives. I was wondering if there's a way to clone the raid array to an external m.2 enclosure either in raid, or jbod or even just onto a single drive? I'm pretty sure it's running as hardware raid, task manager says "Intel Raid 0 volume" but in RST it lists the individual drives that's part of the raid array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can clone it to another drive.  You can use a tool like [CloneZilla](https://clonezilla.org/) to clone the drive to an external USB drive.  Since you are using Intel RST in RAID 0, the volume will just show up as a 1TB drive in CloneZilla.  You can then clone it to another 1TB or larger drive.